# Can i reference a non mapped table in JPA CriteriaBuilder?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to re write the following query using entity manager..

```
public abstract class HibernateEntitySelector<T> extends HibernateDAOSupport implements EntitySelector<T> {
    @Autowired
    public void init(SessionFactory factory) {
        setSessionFactory(factory);
    }
    public String SELECT_IDS = " IN (SELECT RESULT_ID FROM QUERY_RESULTS)";

    public List<T> getEntitiesByIds(){
        DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(getEntityClass());
        criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction(getPrimaryKeyField()+SELECT_IDS));
        return (List<T>) this.getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria);
    }
```

Something like this..

```
public abstract class HibernateEntitySelector<T> implements EntitySelector<T> {

public String SELECT_IDS = " IN (SELECT RESULT_ID FROM QUERY_RESULTS)";

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager em;

    public List<T> getEntitiesByIds(){
        String s = "FROM " + getEntityClass().getSimpleName() + " ent WHERE ent."+getEntityId()+SELECT_IDS;
        Query query = this.em.createNamedQuery(s);
        return (List<T>)query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

But this fails due to `QUERY_RESULTS` not being mapped. Is there a way to do this without using the `createNativeQuery` method and then having to map all the columns manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were quite close, though you are using:

```
Query query = this.em.createNamedQuery(s);
```

Use the createNativeQuery instead and alter the query string alongside also:

```
String s = "SELECT ent.* FROM " + getEntityClass().getSimpleName() + " ent WHERE ent."+getEntityId() + SELECT_IDS;
Query query = this.em.createNativeQuery(s, getEntityClass());
```

Try it out.

Comment: Cheers this worked. I don't know how to mark this as accepted solution. :) Ok found it. doh

Comment: Great! glad it helped